# has_many inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called company that has_many users then users belongs_to company.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

If something belongs to users will it also belong to company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `has_many :through` association for this.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many   :comments
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :comments, :through => :users
end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
c = Company.first
c.users    # returns users
c.comments # returns all the comments made by all the users in the company
```