# How to get all records from a nested activerecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord query that i need help with.

Lets say we have a user and he has multiple libraries.  In each library, there are many collections.  In each collection, he has many books.

How do I get a list of all his books?

I know I can do libraries.each |library| library.collections.each do |collections| collection.books.each do |book| books << book.title

but I'm hoping for a simpler methodology then this.

Comment: You are looking for `has_many through`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512522/has-many-inheritance) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails' has_many through for it

```
class User
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :collections, through: :libraries
  has_many :books, -> { uniq }, through: :collections
end
```

Then you can simply query

```
@user = User.first
@user_books = @user.books
```